# When does travelling at a fraction of the speed of light appear to the traveler as if they're going the speed of light?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, time-dilation

If a spaceship is travelling to Proxima Centari, there is a fraction of the speed of light that would make the spaceship appear to reach Proxima Centauri in four years' time. What fraction of the speed of light would that be?

Comment: From whose perspective?

Comment: @MarkH From the perspective of someone travelling in the spaceship.

Comment: Presumably you know the distance (4.23 light years, which I suspect the question wants you to round to 4 light years)...

Comment: @Floris there should be some value of velocity v that is less than the speed of light that with time dilation causes an observer on the space ship exerience (about) 4 years as the duration of the trip.

Comment: @HowardMiller - I get it; my point was that you need an additional piece of data (the distance) in order to answer the question.

Comment: @Floris Proxima Centauri is approximately 4.24 light years from earth. I'm ignoring for the sake of the question the time required to accelerate to a significant fraction of the speed of light, then decelerating again. At some fraction of the speed of light, an observer on the spaceship would calculate that the closing rate with Proxima Centauri appears to be the speed of light, due to time dilation. My question is, what would this fraction of the speed of light would be?

Comment: $\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}$ I believe

Comment: @Floris that seems to be right, but how do you derive that?

Comment: Per @mephistophales' answer you set $\frac{1}{\gamma}=\frac{v}{c}$, square both sides and solve for $v$.

Answer (score 1):

The proper time $\tau$ for the journey for the traveler is 4 years. The time that passes for someone on earth will be $\gamma \tau$, $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$. For the earth observer, the distance to the star divided by the speed of the rocket is the time the earth observer experiences and equals $\gamma \tau$. So $\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} = \frac{4.22}{\frac{v}{c}}$. Setting c = 1 and solving the last equation for v gives the speed.

Comment: In this case, v would be expressed as some fraction of c?

Comment: Yes a positive number between 0 and 1 times the speed of light.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your formula is correct. Using it, I calculate that traveling at .71c, and observer on the spaceship will experience 4.08 years of elapsed time while traveling 4.24 light years. Obviously the passengers on the space ship will know all about time dilation and won't think they've exceeded the speed of light.

Comment: @Howard Notice that as the proper time for the traveler gets shorter, his velocity gets closer to the speed of light, as it should.

Comment: Getting to any significant fraction of c is gonna be tough.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of Earth or Proxima Centauri, the spaceship will take
$$t = \frac{d}{v}$$
time to make the trip, where $d$ is the distance traveled and $v$ is the velocity of the spaceship. The passengers on the spaceship will experience time dilation, so they will experience
$$t' = \frac{1}{\gamma}\left(\frac{d}{v}\right),$$
where $\gamma$ is the relativistic factor $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}.$$
This ($t'$) is the time you want to set to 4 years.